# How can I design a class named allergy?

Tags: java, class, oop

requirement: design a class named allergy that provides information about the allergy of a patient. e.g. who reported the allergy(patient/doctor/relative), different symptoms of the allergy that are detected, severity, method that returns when was that allergy detected in that patient.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
public abstract class Allergy{
    private String reporter;
    private String symptoms;
    private int timeReported;
    private int severity;

//Higher the number, higher the severity

    public Allergy(String reporter, String symptoms, int timeReported, int severity){
        this.reporter=reporter;
        this.symptoms=symptoms;
        this.timeReported=timeReported;
        this.severity=severity;
    }

    public void setReporter(String reporter){
        this.reporter=reporter;
    }

    public void setSymptoms(String symptoms){
        this.symptoms=symptoms;
    }

    public void setSeverity(int severity){
        this.severity=severity;
    }

    public void setTimeReported(int timeReported){
        this.timeReported=timeReported;
    }

    public String getReporter(){
        return reporter;
    }

    public String getSymptoms(){
        return symptoms;
    }

    public int getSeverity(){
        return severity;
    }

    public int getTimeReported(){
        return timeReported;
    }
}
```

Is this a good design of the class? Is there any way I can improve the design? Or does someone have a better implementation?

I have to be able to explain as many OOP concepts. Can I make use of any other OOP concept here apart from abstract, encapsulation and inheritance that I will be able to use having the current design in my mind?

Comment: Sure.  Lower case `p` for `public`.  And maybe `timeReported` could be a `Date` (if this is Java 7 or below) or an `Instant` (if this is Java 8) instead of an `int`.

Comment: This question appears to be more suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because it asks for opinions about working code. It is not really a good fit for Stack Overflow because it is open-ended with no clear problem to solve.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the code is not working because of the minor syntax errors, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

how about using an enum for severity(low, high, medium) and using an enum for the reporter(patient, doctor, familymember, other) and using HashSet for Symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to have Pojo of allergy and patient. Patient has allergy. However; patient may have allergies then you can add data structure like arrayList of allergy.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax errors mentioned in the comment, and assuming you should not use inheritance, the concept you are missing most are interfaces.
So what you could include an interface Disease (called IDisease) and let the Allergy class implement it, i.e.

```
     public interface IDisease{
          void setReporter(String reporter);
          //other methods
        }

        }

        public class Allergy implements IDisease{
public Allergy(String reporter, String symptoms, int timeReported, int severity){
        this.reporter=reporter;
        this.symptoms=symptoms;
        this.timeReported=timeReported;
        this.severity=severity;
        }

        public void setReporter(String reporter){
        this.reporter=reporter;
        }

        public void setSymptoms(String symptoms){
        this.symptoms=symptoms;
        }

        public void setSeverity(int severity){
        this.severity=severity;
        }

        public void setTimeReported(int timeReported){
        this.timeReported=timeReported;
        }

        public String getReporter(){
        return reporter;
        }

        public String getSymptoms(){
        return symptoms;
        }

        public int getSeverity(){
        return severity;
        }

        public int getTimeReported(){
        return timeReported;
        }
        }
```

Using an interface here could be justified in case later on you would like to write an algorithm to analyse all different kinds of diseases (including Allergies) and would like to keep the algorithm decoupled from the actual details of a particular disease.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason to do this. (Perhaps you should explain why you think this is a good idea.)

Comment: I can make use of any OOP concepts here. I am sorry I wasn't clear in the requirements. I mentioned that using my design I had already implemented abstraction, inheritance( Other child classes like skin allerygy , eye allergy or whatever would have to extend or inherit this abstract class allergy) and encapsulation ( by making variables private). I was asking if I could make use of any other concepts in my current design to make it better? Other than the syntax error, do you think my current design is good enough? Thanks in advance

Comment: added comment why interface could be useful, thx for the hint.